# How to inject object with HK2 in main method in a embedded Grizzly Jersey application

Tags: java, java-8, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a catch 22 problem while designing REST micro services using Jersey. I'm trying to create an application with an embedded grizzly server to reduce deployment complexity. Therefore, I have a main method that creates a grizzly server. I need to inject some object before the server's bootstrap procedure.

My main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App(new MyResourceConfig());
    // Need to inject app here.
    app.init(args);
    app.start();        
}
```

How can I get the `ServiceLocator` singleton instance so I can inject my app object?

I tried:

```
ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance()
                     .create("whatever")
                     .inject(app);
```

However, I need to bind all `AbstractBinder` onto it twice (because I'm already doing it in my `ResourceConfig`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind all you `AbstractBinder`s to the `ServiceLocator` you are creating, then pass that locator to one of the Grizzly server creating factory methods. This will be the parent locator that Jersey will just extract all the services from and stick them into another locator. For example something like

```
ServiceLocator serviceLocator = SLF.getInstance().create(...);
ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(serviceLocator, new Binder1(), new Binder2());
App app = new App();
serviceLocator.inject(app);
HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
        URI.create(BASE_URI),
        resourceConfig, 
        serviceLocator
);
```

You need to make sure you have the Jersey-Grizzly dependency and not just Grizzly.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**See Also:**

- [Javadoc for ServiceLocatorUtilities](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html)
- [Javadoc for GrizzlyHttpServerFactory](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html)

**Note:**

If you are trying to create a Grizzly servlet container with `GrizzlyWebContainerFactory`, trying to make the above work will be difficult. There's is no factory method to pass a locator. Jersey did add support with a property `ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR`, but even then, the property value should be a `ServiceLocator`. The factory method for the grizzly servlet container only accept `Map<String, String>` for init-params. This property was actually added by a third-party contributor that was using Jetty embedded, which did have methods to set init-params with the values as objects. So if you want support for this, you may want to file an issue with Jersey.

Comment: For anyone who finds this later, the [GrizzlyHttpServerFactory](http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/apidocs/2.11/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html) no longer takes a ServiceLocator either as a parameter

Comment: @tzenes [The last parameter I believe](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html#createHttpServer-java.net.URI-org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig-java.lang.Object-)

Answer (score 1):

To extend the great answer from @peeskillet, in my scenario, I had to deploy my Jersey application with other servlets in the same Grizzly servlet container and, indeed, it was a bit of a pain.

But then I've found https://github.com/jersey/jersey/pull/128 which saved my day. Looking at that pull request, this is what I came up with:

```
WebappContext webappContext = new WebappContext("myWebappContext");

webappContext.addListener(new ServletContextListener() {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute(ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR, MY_SERVICE_LOCATOR);
    }
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) { }
});

ServletRegistration servlet = webappContext.addServlet("myAppplication", new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));
servlet.addMapping("/application/*");

ServletRegistration hello = webappContext.addServlet("myServlet", MyServlet.class);
hello.addMapping("/servlet/*");

HttpServer createHttpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(MY_URI, false);
webappContext.deploy(createHttpServer);
createHttpServer.start();
```